# React Native lightbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What is the best module out there right now for image viewing? I wanted to find something like https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox
which has swipe to dismiss features and such. But this module seems to be out of date. Anyone here use anything similar that works with latest version of React Native?

Something I can use to view images, pinch to zoom, swipe to dismiss are kinda essential for my app.

Comment: Every find anything @Thomas?

Comment: Couldn't find anything sadly...

Comment: Does you found solution ?

Answer (score 4):

First you must know about [routerFlux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) . then go to api and read the [LightBox](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#lightbox-lightbox) components...

so here is the simple codes that you make a boxlight:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View , Text } from 'react-native';
import { Router , Scene , Lightbox} from 'react-native-router-flux';


// Components
import ButtonPage from "./components/ButtonPage";
import LoginLightbox from "./components/lightbox/LoginLightbox";


class loginLightbox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex : 1 , justifyContent: 'center' , alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Text>lightBox</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Lightbox>
                    <Scene key="root">
                        <Scene key="button" component={ButtonPage } title="ButtonPage " initial/>
                    </Scene>

                    <Scene key="loginLightbox" component={loginLightbox} />
                </Lightbox>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

and this is the ButtonPage:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container , Button  } from 'native-base';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { form } from './../assets/styles';

export default class ButtonPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Button full style={form.submitButton} onPress={() => Actions.loginLightbox()}>
                    <Text style={form.submitText}>ورود</Text>
                </Button>
            </Container>

        )
    }
}
```

now lets make tow class **BaseLightBox**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated , Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {View, Button, Text, Icon} from 'native-base';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
const { height : deviceHeight , width : deviceWidth} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class BaseLightbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            opacity : new Animated.Value(0)
        }

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.opacity,{
            toValue : 1,
            duration : 200
        }).start();
    }

    close() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.opacity,{
            toValue : 0,
            duration : 200
        }).start(Actions.pop);
    }

    _renderLightbox() {
        const { children , verticalPercent = 1 , horizontalPercent = 1 } = this.props;
        const width = verticalPercent ? deviceWidth * verticalPercent : deviceWidth;
        const height = horizontalPercent ? deviceHeight * horizontalPercent : deviceHeight;
        return (
            <View style={{ width , height, justifyContent: 'center' , alignItems: 'center' , backgroundColor : 'white' , borderRadius : 4}}>
                {children}
                <Button transparent style={{ position: 'absolute', top : 0 , left : 0}} onPress={() => this.close() }>
                    <Icon name='md-close-circle' style={{ fontSize : 30 , color : '#34495e'}}/>
                </Button>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.View style={[styles.container , { opacity : this.state.opacity }]}>
                {this._renderLightbox()}
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }

}

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(52,52,52,.5)',
        position: 'absolute',
        top : 0 ,
        bottom : 0,
        left : 0,
        right : 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})
```

and **LoginLightBox**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated , Text } from 'react-native';
import BaseLightbox from "./BaseLightbox";


export default class LoginLightbox extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <BaseLightbox verticalPercent={0.7} horizontalPercent={0.5}>
                <Text>Welcome to roocket</Text>
                <Text>Learn React native</Text>
            </BaseLightbox>
        )
    }
}
```